# Swift Terminal Emulator: errors in complex commands

Tags: swift, macos, terminal, terminal-emulator

I'm trying to create a Terminal Emulator using Swift and so far I've gotten all the basic functionality. I can send commands like `diskutil list` and get their correct output. But if I require the program to be interactive in anyway such as `sudo reboot` where the user must specify their password, I get the error `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`; or perhaps when I want to use `nano anyTextFile.txt`, I'll get an error like `Error opening terminal: unknown.` I don't see anything within the `Process` class that has anything to do with specifying a TTY or an askpass (whatever that is)

Here's my code that should be relevant to this question:

```
func shell(_ args: String) -> (output: [String], error: [String], exitCode: Int32) {
    var output : [String] = []
    var error : [String] = []


    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    let cmd = args.characters.split(separator: " ").map(String.init)
    task.arguments = cmd

    let outpipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = outpipe
    let errpipe = Pipe()
    task.standardError = errpipe

    task.launch()

    let outdata = outpipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    if var string = String(data: outdata, encoding: .utf8) {
        string = string.trimmingCharacters(in: .newlines)
        output = string.components(separatedBy: "\n")
    }

    let errdata = errpipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    if var string = String(data: errdata, encoding: .utf8) {
        string = string.trimmingCharacters(in: .newlines)
        error = string.components(separatedBy: "\n")
    }

    task.waitUntilExit()
    let status = task.terminationStatus

    return (output, error, status)
}
```

Comment: Show your code, otherwise there's not enough here for anyone to help you...

Comment: Sorry - must've forgotten! Thanks!